# Why isn't ->[] an operator in C++? (a subscript operator for dereferenced array pointers)

Tags: c++, programming-languages, operators

I know asking *Why?* is a bad question for this site, since we can't know. However I mean it as a colloquial replacement for asking, *What are some possible reasons?*

I found myself writing, naturally,

```
foo->[i];
```

and being surprised to learn that it didn't work. I meant to write:

```
(*foo)[i];
```

I'm sure most see already what I mean, but to be clear, I thought

```
bar.subscript(i);
foo->subscript(i);
```

would be analogous to

```
bar.operator[](i);
foo->operator[](i);
```

**But this doesn't seem to be the case. Why?** I'm certain I must be looking at something the wrong way, but I can't figure out what. I know very little theory, so a layperson's explanation would be appreciated.

**If there's no obvious error in my analogy though, then what are some possible reasons the designers of the language may have left the operator out?** Is it ambiguous? (If so, as being mistakable for what?)

---

I'd like to bring some comments into an edit, as per @chris's recommendation, as I have not been as clear as I should have been:

> *The OP is proposing operator->[], a combination of the two.*
> – chris

> *He's asking why the thing he wants doesn't exist, not why the code he's trying to write doesn't work.*
> – Matthew 'Cogwheel' Orlando

Comment: An interesting question is "would it be hard to parse".  I do not know the answer to that question.

Comment: @Yakk, I doubt it with maximal munch in effect. I was about to comment on that.

Comment: Because nobody thought of it at the time and nobody has yet cared enough to make it standard. This is the reason behind 99% of "X seems good, why doesn't C++ have X" questions. This is especially true of questions like this: it's a lot easier to tell people to write `(*x).[i]` instead of `x->[i]`, rather than do all the work of changing the standard text, testing it, making sure there's no horrible oversight, etc...

Comment: I like how the question asks why doesn't "foo->[i];" but then uses the correct "foo->operator[](i);" in the explanation for why it _should_ work.

Comment: @GManNickG: I have run into code where I _had_ to use the `.operator->()` form for things (iterator wrapper), so people should also know that that is an option.

Comment: Wouldn't this be ambiguous when used together with a _lambda_ evaluated right after its defined which returns a _member-pointer_?

Comment: @K-Ballo, you'd have to use `->*` in that case methinks.  Currently, the only legal token after operator `->` is either a `*` (which changes which operator), or the name of a member, I believe?

Comment: @K-ballo, Something along the lines of `obj->[]{return blah;}()`? Won't compile (doesn't like the `[`), so I guess not.

Comment: @Yakk, chris: Right, I was thing about `->*`

Comment: @K-ballo, Eh, I can't even get it to combine `->*` and a lambda.

Comment: @chris: Something like this `struct test{ int member; }; test* obj; obj->*[](){ return &test::member; }();`

Comment: @K-ballo, Odd, I have absolutely no idea what I was doing for it to not compile now. ... Oh wait, I had a static const member in the class for other reasons. Good one me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what are some possible reasons the designers of the language may have left the operator out?

1: Nobody proposed it. If it doesn't get proposed, it doesn't get into the language.

2: It looks wrong. `operator->` may return a pointer, but the *use* of it in the language is "reference this pointer and access a member". That's what the language will do with `->`. So when someone sees `->[]`, it looks incorrect. The thing to the right of `->` in every other case is some form of member identifier.

3: Because there are far more important things to do with the language than change something minor like this.

Comment: `foo->(bar) = baz->[snaf]` -- oo, and don't forget `foo->++`!  Oh, and `foo->[bar]->[snaf]->[meh] = 7` -- think of the syntax we could get from this!

Comment: Ah, okay. No, I agree, maybe it wasn't a proposal worth making, much less a change worth making. I was more asking because I thought there was something wrong in my logic, not simply that there was a human/subjective factor. Thank you.

Comment: @Yakk - Ah, actually, I find your examples shed light on a great reason as to why this one may have been omitted! I didn't realize the slew of other operators that would have to be introduced to be consistent with what I'm saying.

Answer (score 4):

The right of **operator->** must be the name of a member. An explicit **operatorXYZ** counts as the name of a member I guess, so **foo->operator[]** is allowed. However, a random token such as **[]** doesn't count as the name of a member, so **foo->[i]** is not allowed.

Comment: That's why it would be made to be the equivalent of `operator->[](foo, i);`.

Comment: If this is the answer, then I don't quite understand it, yet...

Comment: @acheong87, This answer lies upon a basis that `->` and `[]` are two separate operators. Merging them into one, as you ask, would cause it to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine the reason is that in C++ there is a significant chance that you would be using `vector` (or `array` in C++1) instead of pointers-to-C-arrays. In the C++-centric solutions there is no need for such an operator so it was probably deemed extra work for the compiler while providing little to no benefit.

If you need a 2d array then `foo[0][i]` already works with C-arrays.

Comment: Huh? I can see a use for this operator any time you have a pointer or iterator to something with an `operator[]`, which seems more likely in C++ than in C (though not terribly common overall).